# How to flexibly select a single method or class from a long list of sequentially named methods or classes

Tags: java

I know the simple way is to use a `switch` statement, but that is not what I am asking. I want to know, if I can call a method, based on its name as a `String` that I can modify from the user's input.

For example, I have a bunch of methods named:

- `func01`
- `func02`
- `func03`
- ...

I want to call them using a string `"func"`, which I modify by adding a numerical suffix to it, like `01`, `02` or `03`. I want call them using a few lines of code that will work for any number of methods.

Comment: What is the signature of those methods? Do they all have the same signature? Are they **static** or instance methods?

Comment: func01(),  func02() and so on. I don't mind static or instantiated as long the purpose is fulfilled, I'll modify them or make a workaround in future if such specifics exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with Reflection

You could use **Reflection** to call the methods.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        // Just an example calling all the methods
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

            Object object = invokeMethod("func", i);

            if (object != null) {
                // Do something with object, cast it, etc. ...
            } else {
                // Error calling the methods
            }

        }

    }

    private static Object invokeMethod(String methodBaseName, int number) {

        // Number format will be two digits padded by zeros,
        // e.g. 01, 02, ..., 18, ...
        // For three digits use "%03d" and so on or calculate
        // the digits from the number itself
        String methodName = methodBaseName + String.format("%02d", number);

        try {
            Method methodToInvoke = MethodClass.class.getMethod(methodName);
            return methodToInvoke.invoke(new MethodClass());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Alternatively handle this errors
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class MethodClass {

    public Object func01() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public Object func99() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Alternatively for `static` methods, just use:

```
Method method = MethodClass.class.getMethod(...);
method.invoke(MethodClass.class);
```

If you want to add parameters, modify the code like this:

```
getMethod(methodName, parameterType1.class, parameterType2.class, ...);
invoke(..., parameter1, parameter2, ...);
```

If you want to use a return value, just change the return type from `Object` to the concrete type and cast the return value from `invoke` to this type, e.g. `Integer`:

```
Integer result = (Integer) method.invoke(...);
```

### Important notice

What you are trying to do is very dangerous. Reflection can be a critical harm for the security of your application. You should **never** allow a user to input a method name to invoke a method, otherwise he or she could potentially call any method to gain control of your application or memory. Beware of this.

Comment: Updated solution and added a notice to **reflection and security**.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to implement using string as name. Just a query, is thepublic object func01() {
        // ...
    } is it "object" or "Object"

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it must be `Object`. Loop bound also corrected to `100` and extended return value remark. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the security tip, I know and I'll use it for only non harmful methods.

Comment: Sorry I Didn't add any statements to function, it works perfect now

Comment: If this or the other answers solved your problem, please accept any, so the question does not appear unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using reflection. If your method is static, use the code like this:

```
Method method = ClassName.class.getMethod(name, param1.getClass(), param2.getClass(), ..);
method.invoke(ClassName.class, param1, param2, ..);
```

Or if your method isn't static, use the code like this:

```
Method method = object.getClass().getMethod(name, param1.getClass(), param2.getClass(), ..);
method.invoke(object, param1, param2, ..);
```

Comment: Thankyou, that was spot on. I'm getting nosuchmethodexception error but I'll google it.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a dangerous and almost impossible feature to use correctly for new Java programmers. Obtaining a method or other object-oriented element via a string is an antipattern; it breaks type safety, is very difficult to maintain and debug, and will cause you endless bugs. I speak from experience.

Instead, use a single method with overrides for each type of action you want, and let object orientation help you. If you really need a string to tell you which logic flow to use, perhaps an enum will rescue you. You can use the `valueOf()` method to parse the string into a valid enum, then call the desired functionality through each enum constant's implementation of an abstract method in the enum.

```
public class Processor
{
  FOLD
  {
    @Override
    public void process()
    {
      // fold logic
    }
  },
  SPINDLE
  {
    @Override
    public void process()
    {
      // spindle logic
    }
  },
  MUTILATE
  {
    @Override
    public void process()
    {
      // mutilate logic
    }
  },
  ;

  abstract public void process();
}
```

Your client code will be similar to

```
Processor.valueOf(text).process();
```

with suitable error checking and exception handling, of course.